# Is it possible to run node server in Express with only git-tracked files?

Tags: node.js, git, express, nodemon

I would like to run my Express app but only with files that are currently tracked in Git. For example, here is my current status of Git (`git status`):

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
 (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    blogs/test_announcement.md
    public/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
    public/css/bootstrap.min.css
    routes/twitter.js

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

However, when I tried to run the server (I use `nodemon`), it seems that there is no way to ignore the untracked files. This makes the blog `test_announcement` displayed on the website.

Ultimately, I'm going to push my local files managed under git to a remote PaaS so there wouldn't be a problem on the production. However, it is pretty stressful to see the untracked files in development phase.

So is there any possible way to ignore those files locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is add those files to a separate git branch and checkout a different branch when you want to test without them. For example, keep your `master` branch clean but you could have a private `local-drafts` branch with not-to-be-published files.

Comment: This is the right answer. I couldn't understand the use case for this functionality. If you aren't using branches suddenly it does. So the answer "use branches".